# java - invoke method with void return type from another class

Tags: java

Here's the first package

```
    package mainPkg;

    import java.util.List;
    import mypkg.mylib;


    public class myClass {

        private static String inputFile = "";

        public myClass(String inFile){
            //  Set input file
            inputFile = inFile;
        }

        // Read input from input file as matrix
        mylib mlib = new mylib();

        String[][] dData = mlib.transformArr(someData);

        //Print matrix
        mlib.printarr(dData);
    }
```

Here's the second package

```
package mypkg;

public class mylib {

    public void printarr(String[][] inputArray) {
        for (int row = 0; row < inputArray.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < inputArray[0].length; col++) {
                System.out.println(inputArray[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In eclipse IDE, against the function call `mlib.printarr(dData);` I see the below compilation errors

```
    Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
    Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
```

I ahve a bunch of other functions that are defined in the class `mylib` with a return type other than `void` such as the function `convertTomatrix` ( I've not included that here as it works fine). I can invoke these functions without problem. I've looked online to see if there is a special way to invoke functions with `void` return type but doesn't seem to be anything special.

Is there anything syntactically incorrect here? Any pointers would help please.

Comment: Yes there is. I see your code is not in a method

Comment: Is this the real code that gives you this error?

Comment: The last 3 lines of code in `public class myClass` either needs to be in static block or a method for the class to understand when it needs to execute the set of instructions.

Comment: Add last 3 statement of `myClass` inside a main or any other method

Comment: Where is your static method ??

Comment: Thank you all. Appreciate your help. It's a bit confusing for a newbie with these stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the contents to main function as suggested